# Select best database option for meta data collection

Tags: database, stream, time-series, storage, analysis

I am developing a VMS plugin that like others, sends frames to an analysis process, then retrieves metadata and shows overlays related to these metadata on the live video. For example like the image below:
[image: video with metadata overlay sample]
up to here, I have had no problems or questions. The question comes from when I want to collect these metadata and make an archive, so that in the playback mode when the operator is watching a recorded video, I can again draw those metadata overlays on the screen although without asking the analysis engine to do the job again.
So I have to:

1. For each frame (for example 1 frame per second) store a metadata object
2. On playback mode for each frame again, read the related stored metadata object
3. As the times may not be an exact match, find a period (for example from one second ago to the frame time)
4. Keep the records sorted so that when selecting the last, has the correct metadata
5. Define a process (a job) to remove old records periodically

---

in this scenario I encounter big stream-like data and continuous reading in playback mode. So which type of databases can handle this type of store and fetch actions? Can SQL databases like SQLite and PostgreSQL do this or do I have to use time series databases like influxDB?